# Objective C get XML from URL

Tags: objective-c, xml

So after scouring the internet for multiple days and endless night grinding my forehead against a cheese-grater I come to stackoverflow with a question that may have been asked before, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Simply what I want to achieve is to get an XML file from a remote location on a web server with a URL and then turn it into an array.

So far, this is what I've gotten up to given multiple website's and documentation.

```
NSURL *xmlString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/query.xml"];

NSDictionary *dictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlString];

NSLog(@"XML is %@",dictionary);

NSArray *XMLarray=[[dictionary valueForKey:@"Result"] valueForKey:@"Table"];
```

and the output in the console is

```
XML is (null)
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fixey?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Is it a general XML file? The code you have will only work if the XML represents a plist file created with a dictionary as the root.

Comment: @rmaddy It's just a plain normal XML file with nothing extra. How could I get my application to read it without a plist file?

Comment: You can't simply load an arbitrary XML file directly in an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`. You need to use an XML parser and parse the XML into the desired format.

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried doing that. Never seemed to ever get it working. Examples all over the internet haven't shed any light on the situation either :/

Comment: Then post what you have tried and explain what issues you are having.

Answer (score 5):

There is a classic bit of code which does this: [Simple XML to NSDictionary Converter](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/).

There are a few implementations of this on github

- https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader
- https://github.com/gouravgupta72/XMLReader
- https://github.com/rcdilorenzo/XMLReader

It's pretty easy:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/query.xml"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:&error];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'XMLReader'`. I'm assuming I need to import it, but I'm new to xcode/objc and would have no idea how to do it properly

Comment: @SteppingHat `XMLReader` is not built in. You either need to create the class yourself (based on the tutorial in the first link), or you can clone an pre-done version.